# Server for handling data manipulation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have currently built application in which I handle Products, Accounts, Orders, etc.

There are two databases one is  a database which I created where I handle Users and Roles and some minor Application specific data. The other database is external and it is the one which holds all the data about Orders, Products and Accounts.

What I am trying to figure out is: how to build a server which runs parallel to the main application and handles all data manipulation with the external database.

Let's say a situation in which this would be helpful: There is an excel file which has to be created based on big amount of data and afterwards it has to be stored in the externalDB as certain type of format and sent as Email to someone. This will surely overload the main thread of the main application, hence we don't want that. Therefore, it would be a good idea to handle those kind of situations outside user's vision.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and was curious what would be a good approach for this situation? I was thinking that I should make Console application, which is working as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a service architecture and have the services communicate with each other through controllers.  These could push data back to the main application views, or the views could request data push from the services.

If you wanted to have jobs etc running on that server that send emails, you could easily just create SQL jobs or SSIS jobs or even custom service jobs that did that based on your criteria that are separate from the main view (where view is the main application that the user interacts with)

Services themselves could be configured with a light User Interface that you could call up on the server, perhaps in the service tray or through the Services component of Windows.

SOA architecture
https://www.cleverism.com/how-to-build-service-oriented-architecture-soa/

Micro Service architecture
http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do these kinds of things.

If your applications are for Android or iOS devices, it's common practice to have an external server running which handles intensive processing including managing your excel data, sending emails and database communication.

If your applications are cross-platform desktop applications or OS-specific desktop applications, you can still be able to use the external server, although certain other parts of the processing may be done on the client machine.

By using a web service to deal with database communication, it makes the applications more secure in regards to hard-coded database connection information, SMTP server credentials etc.

Using a RESTful web service will mean that you're adhering to the Hypertext Transfer Protocol ([HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)) which is great for exchanging data in the majority of cases.

Using a console application which acts as a TCP client server allows you to use the Transmission Control Protocol ([TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)) to communicate in a different way. You're able to pass on data in a custom format if you wish. You'd be able to create a standard for communication which your applications will need to stick to.

The console application would do the same processing as the web service, however you would be in full control of logging requests, responses and data transfer.